# ASP.NET Web Pages questions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-webpages

I'm new to ASP.NET, but have been using PHP for many years. I have started on a educational program, where we are forced to learn ASP.NET, and I'm trying to find the best way.

As i understand there are three different development models you can choose between, when you code ASP.NET:

- Web Pages
- Web Forms
- MVC

I found out that "Web Pages" seems to be easiest model to use, because it reminds more about PHP than the other two models.

So i have some questions about the model "Web Pages":

- Is the model (Web Pages) as powerful as the other two models in terms of built in utilities, just like PHP has a lot built in functions.
- Can you do OOP using the model?
- Can you do functions?
- I don't know how advanced the model is, so the questions is if this model restricts me in building something that you can only do with the two other model?
- Can i use c# using the model.
- Do you have any links to advanced tutorials about this model.

Thanks.

Comment: WP is for very beginners (I think). The right choices are WF and MVC when using a .NET Web framework. MVC is more object oriented than WF. You can easily make Unit Tests to test your pages, which would be very difficult in WF. But WF has more built in features. I think easier to learn WF and if you have no big project with complicated business logic, its better choose than MVC. If you choose WF I highly recommend to avoid using the smart UI (only draggin-dropping things and write code to the code behind).

Comment: Web pages are nothing other then html and css combined. As for learning web development there are Web Forms and MVC technologies. you can use C# in both and c# is oop. You can do whatever you used to do in PHP using ASP.NET I recommend you read this http://www.asp.net/web-forms

Comment: @Sam See this: http://www.asp.net/web-pages

Comment: In addition to Web Forms, Web Pages, and MVC you could also consider plain HTML files or Single Page Application projects  if you rely heavily on Web API for server communication.

Comment: Also worth noting that in ASP.NET 5 (vNext) the MVC, Web API, and Web Pages distinctions are all going away. They'll [all be rolled into MVC](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/aspnet-5-overview#unify).

Answer (score 2):

The Web Pages model is just one entry point to developing dynamic sites using ASP.NET. Behind it is the same .NET library that lies behind the other two entry points: Web Forms and MVC. Whatever you can do in MVC and Web Forms, you can also do in Web Pages. You are not restricted to a subset of functionality.

Both C# and VB (your language choices for Web Pages) are fully object-oriented, so you can use OOP as much as you like when developing with Web Pages.

I have written a [lot of articles on using Web Pages for web site development](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Category/27), including many that feature advanced OOP-based concepts such as Code-First development using the Entity Framework, and incorporating class libraries into an ASP.NET Web Pages site for data access code.

Comment: @user977150 THIS! After having chosen the Web-Pages option and programmed in it for over a year, I must say I am personally NOT disappointed in the slightest. I do feel like it is easier for beginners, but as Mike stated, you are not restricted to a subset of functionality. Web-Pages has access to the SAME ASP.NET that the other two options do. When it comes to being a pro at Web-Pages, I know of no one more fitting than Mike Brind (he's helped me a lot), and his website: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/ is insanely useful and the easiest read (for programming) that there is, IMO. I have...

Comment: ...never ran into anything I just "couldn't do" because of Web-Pages. I can also say that it seems that Web-Pages is more for the solo programmer, (as opposed to MVC, which is better for teams of programmers). As for Web-Forms, I don't really know what the strengths and/or weaknesses are there. In any event, I can say that I have commonly heard Web-Pages referred to as *"simple yet powerful."*

Comment: @user977150 Also, there exists the option to still use PHP in Web-Pages, as well. All you have to do is click the "Site" tab in WebMatrix, click "Settings", and then simply check the "Enable PHP" checkbox. From there it should be the same setup as normal.